# Write to file without \" symbols haskell

Tags: file, haskell, file-io

For example need this text to write a file:

`This is some simple text "it's quote", test test`

I use `writeFile :: FilePath -> String -> IO ()` to write file, but when i try to write this string in the file, in file i see:

`This is some simple text \"it\'s quote\", test test`

How can i remove \ symbols, i need in only " without \ in my text file.

Thank you.

Comment: `writeFile` does not add backslashes. Other functions do. Show a full compilable program.

Comment: Are you calling `show` on the string before writing it?

Comment: Then just remove `show`, it adds the escaping.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting is added to `String` types via the `show` function. If you just write the string directly, it will not be escaped.